# Do the other Ronin Warriors receive power upgrades?

Tags: ronin-warriors

In the series *Ronin Warriors* (or, *Yoroiden Samurai Troopers*), the main character and red <strike>Power Ranger</strike> armored team lead, Ryo, eventually gets an armor upgrade.

In similar Sentai team shows like Sailor Moon, the supporting teammates also get "power ups" during the course of the show's run. Does this happen in any continuity of the Ronin Warriors franchise at all?

Comment: Which armor upgrade are you referring to? The Armor of Inferno?

Comment: @LunarGuy Yup! That Armor is basically *Moon Cosmic Power, Make-up!* But more ~manly~.

Comment: I don't think the Ronin Warriors did, but the Power Rangers all later got upgrades.  There was always the odd man out though: For example, Tommy the green or White Ranger IIRC.